# How to read ruby profiler's output

Tags: ruby, profiling, profiler

Let us take an example from the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/profiler/rdoc/Profiler__.html):

```
require 'profile'

def slow_method
  5000.times do
    9999999999999999*999999999
  end
end

def fast_method
  5000.times do
    9999999999999999+999999999
  end
end

slow_method
fast_method
```

Output:

```
  %   cumulative   self              self     total
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name
 68.42     0.13      0.13        2    65.00    95.00  Integer#times
 15.79     0.16      0.03     5000     0.01     0.01  Fixnum#*
 15.79     0.19      0.03     5000     0.01     0.01  Fixnum#+
  0.00     0.19      0.00        2     0.00     0.00  IO#set_encoding
  0.00     0.19      0.00        1     0.00   100.00  Object#slow_method
  0.00     0.19      0.00        2     0.00     0.00  Module#method_added
  0.00     0.19      0.00        1     0.00    90.00  Object#fast_method
  0.00     0.19      0.00        1     0.00   190.00  #toplevel
```

- `% time` is how much time spent in those methods.
- `cumulative seconds` are previous `cumulative seconds` plus `self seconds`, that is, `0 + 0.13 = 0.13`, `0.13 + 0.03 = 0.16`, `0.16 + 0.03 = 0.19`, and so on.
- `self seconds` are `% time` measured in seconds.
- `calls` says how many times the method was called.
- `self ms/call` is `self seconds` / `calls`.
- What is `total ms/call`?

Comment: I see that `(130/0.6842)/2 #=> 95.001...` A clue, perhaps?

Comment: @CarySwoveland The calculation does not fit other rows. I'd say the `total ms/call` means time in ms per method call since first stack entered from the top-level, not from the closest outer stack - that's `self ms/call`. The base value is not in the table, only number of calls so deriving the formula from it is meaningless.

Comment: It seems this is the correct meaning: [Profiler source](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/lib/profiler.rb#60)

Comment: It's yet another [*gprof clone*](https://archive.is/9r927). It says `Profiling your program is a way of determining which methods are called and
how long each method takes to complete.  This way you can detect which methods are possible bottlenecks.` Wrong.

Comment: I indeed was going to try `ruby-prof`. Just wanted to clear things up, concerning this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** `self seconds` + time spent in called methods

Okay, let us dig into the [source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_3/lib/profiler.rb). There are two `proc`s, gathering information there: [`PROFILE_CALL_PROC`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_3/lib/profiler.rb#L79-L83), [`PROFILE_RETURN_PROC`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_3/lib/profiler.rb#L84-L97). The former gets called before stepping into a method, the latter before stepping out.

`@@maps[Thread.current]` accumulates information about methods, namely [`calls`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_3/lib/profiler.rb#L91), [`total seconds`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_3/lib/profiler.rb#L93) (`cost`), [`self seconds`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_3/lib/profiler.rb#L94) and [`name`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_3/lib/profiler.rb#L90) in this particular order. This very information is served later to the user, in a more wordy fashion. After being [aggregated](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_3/lib/profiler.rb#L123-L131).

`@@stacks[Thread.current]` stores information about methods being run, in a stack. Namely "when the method was started", and "how much time does called (child) methods took" (`tick[1]`). This is more of a temporary data structure destined to help gathering data into `@@maps`.

As one can supposedly see now, [`self seconds`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_3/lib/profiler.rb#L94) is [`total seconds`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_3/lib/profiler.rb#L93) minus [`cost`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_3/lib/profiler.rb#L95) (time spent in called methods). That is, `total seconds` is a time spent both in the method itself and in the methods it calls.

P.S. Pretty much reminds [flat profiles](https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof/blob/master/examples/flat.txt) in `ruby-prof`.

Answer (score 0):

A method may spend time on its own, or spend time due to time spent by the methods it calls. `self ms/call` only counts the former, while `total ms/call` counts the sum of both. It makes sense to represent `self seconds`, but not `total seconds` because that would be cumulate all over the place.

Comment: How do you figure self time makes sense?

Comment: @MikeDunlavey Because the method with a large `self seconds` is where you want to improve.

Comment: Only if the program is tiny. Check the second answer [*here*](https://archive.is/9r927).